# Regex expression to remove '\t' under a specific condition in a long string

Tags: c#, regex, tabs

I have the following string:

```
"\"PARTINST:SCHEM:03_INTERFACES:17188\"\t\"R-303\"\t\"R-303\"\t\"50.0 K\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"4313963\"\t\"RES 0603 50.0 KOHM 0.1% 63MW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"1.000\"\t\"TE CONNECT\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"9\"\t\"\"\t\"NO\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"BOT\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"Vishay\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"RES 0603 50.0 KOHM 0.1% 63MW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"+\"\t\"\"\t\"RES.Normal\"\t\"1040\"\t\"90\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"TE CONNECTIVITY\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"0603r\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"False\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"3\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"N:\\TRAVAIL\\LIBRAIRIE_CAO\\LIBRAIRIE\\DISCRETS.OLB\"\t\"RES\"\t\"RES.Normal\"\t\"0.02\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"1mW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\r"
```

I'm trying to remove the '\t' pattern thanks to regex in the string when some text precedes it, and keep it when it's alone.
For now, I have this regex `\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\\t\"` which enables me to find all the text bewteen quotation marks and having a '\t' following it, but however should be adapted to the condition mentioned above.
For example:

```
"\t\"TE CONNECT\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"
```

and

```
"\t\"0603r\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"False\t"\t\"<null>\"
```

would become

```
"\t\"TE CONNECT\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1"\t\"<null>\"\t\"
```

and

```
"\t\"0603r\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1"\t\"False"\t\"<null>\"
```

Comment: "keep it when it's alone" this part is not really clear to me. does it mean when it is not inside the `"` ? another thing: please check the formatting and escaping sequences. Why would this: `\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"` become `\"CKF0603949K9E1"` ? is it a typo that the second escaping slash is missing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. By "keep it when it's alone" I mean not to remove it when in the string it is under the form "\t\" alone (no text preceding the \t). The second slash is indeed missing, so it should look like \"CKF0603949K9E1\".

Comment: Yes that's the case, that's why it is kept. By alone I mean:  "\t\" -> alone but "CKF0603949K9E1\t\" -> not alone.

Comment: Because it is "\t" and not in the form "\SOMETEXT\t\" (I want to convert that to "\SOMETEXT\"). Anyways, I have found a workaround by using `myString = myString.Replace("\t\"\t\"", "\"\t");` . I would however still be interested and curious in having a Regex solution.

Comment: oh my goodness, I am sorry mate. I switch the conditions in my head. ok you are right. :D I get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the '\t' pattern via regex in the string when some text precedes it, and keep it when it's alone ?

I think I found the regex pattern. You can read it in the variable **replacingPattern**.

Here is what I propose to achieve that via Regex :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputText = "\"PARTINST:SCHEM:03_INTERFACES:17188\"\t\"R-303\"\t\"R-303\"\t\"50.0 K\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"4313963\"\t\"RES 0603 50.0 KOHM 0.1% 63MW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"1.000\"\t\"TE CONNECT\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"9\"\t\"\"\t\"NO\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"BOT\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"Vishay\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"RES 0603 50.0 KOHM 0.1% 63MW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"+\"\t\"\"\t\"RES.Normal\"\t\"1040\"\t\"90\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"NO\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"TE CONNECTIVITY\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"0603r\"\t\"CKF0603949K9E1\t\"\t\"False\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"3\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"N:\\TRAVAIL\\LIBRAIRIE_CAO\\LIBRAIRIE\\DISCRETS.OLB\"\t\"RES\"\t\"RES.Normal\"\t\"0.02\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"1mW\"\t\"<null>\"\t\"<null>\"\r";

    string replacingPattern = "(?:(?<=\\\"))\\t*?(?:(?=\\\"))";

    Regex rgx = new Regex(replacingPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    string result = rgx.Replace(inputText, "£");

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue ...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Can you test it and tell me if it's ok for you, please ?

Comment: Note that your regex engine must support lookbehinds and lookaheads.

Comment: If you want to try it in https://regex101.com, you should use the following unescaped regular expression:  `(?:(?<=\\"))\\t*?(?:(?=\\"))`